# Access part of SimpleXMLElement Object - PHP

Tags: php, object, simplexml

I need to loop through the `items` as an array within the SimpleXMLElement Object below but cannot seem to access it using `$order->order->order->items`. I can access the delivery and billing addresses using the same format, ie. `$order->order->order->delivery_address` and expected to get to the items array in the same way.  However, I get an empty SimpleXMLElement Object when I `print_r($order->order->order->items)`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 860268
            [shopkeeper_orderno] => 1001
            [customer] => 797476
            [creationdate] => Apr 19 2012 10:36:38:100AM
            [reference] => k2koju45rmaqfl45n20xbkmq
            [net] => 1500
            [vat] => 17.5
            [status] => 0
            [isnew] => 1
            [deductions] => 0
            [postage] => 1
            [paymentmethod] => PayPal              
            [instructions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [errors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [kashflow_synch] => 0
            [order] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [billing_address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [0] => 

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [delivery_address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [0] => 

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1285158
                                            [headerID] => 860268
                                            [productID] => 4867690
                                            [description] => TEST ORDERING PF NODES - Special Offer Price
                                            [net] => 1400
                                            [vat] => 0
                                            [qty] => 1
                                            [formID] => -1
                                        )

                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1285159
                                            [headerID] => 860268
                                            [productID] => 4959678
                                            [description] => Wedding dress
                                            [net] => 100
                                            [vat] => 17.5
                                            [qty] => 1
                                            [formID] => -1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [postage_tax] => 0
            [dispatched] => 0
            [paybyotherid] => -1
            [ip] => 81.168.43.121   
            [wheredidyouhearid] => -1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dan Lees suggestion I tried SimpleXMLElement::children() and did the below which works

```
foreach ($order->children() as $order) {
        foreach ($order->children() as $order_details) {
            foreach ($order_details->children() as $order_items) {
                echo $order_items->id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I just saw you made a mistake with the naming, the parent needs to be called `<orders>` and the sub items `<order>`

---

The SimpleXMLElement *seems* to be empty, in fact it's usually filled but not displayed when dumping (whoever thought of this crazy behaviour)

Can you try this?

```
foreach($order->orders->order as $order) { // should be orders then
  echo $item->getName();
}
```

Or try it with [SimpleXMLElement::children()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)

Comment: I cannot change the XML so that the parent is orders.  I need to work with what I have.  The above gives me "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error

Answer (score 1):

your items are actually on the second offset of the order array.

I'd just use the xPath to process these.

```
foreach($xmlObject->xpath('/order/order[2]/items') as $item)
{
   // Do something with my $item
}
```

Comment: I don't have direct access to the XML only have the above to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop like the one below, then all you need to do is $items->id

```
   foreach($order->children()->children()->items as $items)
      {

      }
```